# Spring boot Testing - Mock configurations

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

I want to write test for one of my Spring Service and one of the method in service  is like this:

```
private void loadConfig() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
     // it loads config.json file and sets it in global variable
}
```

It loads the **`config.json`** file from classpath.

Now my question is: Is it possible to somehow define that for Tests

**it should look for config-test.json instead of config.json** ? Assume i have config-test.json on my classpath.

May be some annotation on method, I did not find much help from official doc.

Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use filename as method parameter, or try to use `@PropertySource` and Spring `Environment` for each `ApplicationContext` production as well as test.